# adding slidedown event on a jquery menu

Tags: jquery, html

Ok I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
var timeout         = 0;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{   jsddm_canceltimer();
jsddm_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('#as').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');
bb = $(this).css("background","#0099FF");
}

function jsddm_close()
{
if(ddmenuitem)
ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function jsddm_timer()
{   closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
bb = $(this).css("background","none");
}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{   if(closetimer)
    {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{


$("#sinputbox").watermark("Search item here...");
$('#menu > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
$('#menu > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;

</head>
<body>
<div id="hmenu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.php?name=gallery">Gallery</a>
    <ul id="as">
            <li><a href="gallery.php?name=clothing">Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php?name=furniture">Furniture</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php?name=householditems">Household-items</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php?name=automotive">Automotive</a> </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php?name=food">Food</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I am planning to add a slidedown to that dropdown menu but I don't know how. I tried to add this line: "`$('this').slideDown('slow');`" inside this function: "`function jsddm_timer()`" but nothing work so far. Could someone here help me to this pls? I'm open in any suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JSFiddle and tell if you want functionality like this:

Updated Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/qFEJh/1/

And this is the UPDATED Code

```
function jsddm_open()
{
    $(this).find('#as').slideDown('slow');
    bb = $(this).css("background","#0099FF");
}

function jsddm_close()
{
    $(this).find('#as').slideUp('slow');
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#menu > li:has(ul)').hover(jsddm_open,jsddm_close);
});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

Comment: working, but whenever i hover to other parent menu the css background color state of the current parent menu that I hover basically the gallery which hold has the dropdown is staying, it should be switched, i mean whenever its been unhover the css background color should be switched to none.

Answer (score 0):

In your case wouldn't it be:

```
$(this).find('#as').eq(0).slideDown('slow');
```

Assuming you put this in your `jsddm_open` function.